# Failed while installing Liferay Theme 6.0

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

Facing issue while importing a Liferay project into eclipse

Saying :

```
'Creating SDK Projects' has encountered a problem.

Failed while installing Liferay Theme 6.0
```

Comment: Add some info about what are you trying to do.as now we can't help you

Comment: refresh the workspace

Comment: Consider yourself lucky that you got an upvote from some really charitable (but blind) person. Can you provide us with some more information? How do you suppose we guess what's on your system which is causing trouble. Version of sdk, eclipse version, liferay IDE or liferay dev studio, version of it, how was the liferay project created in the first place which u are importing, how are you importing the project?